# Auto generate the ''To'' field when sending Email on Opportunity

Tags: email, opportunity, activities, process-automation

On Opportunity --> Activity --> Email.

Does someone know how to auto populate the fiel 'To' related to the Contact email?
For now, I need to copy paste the email address, I am looking for an automatic solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with the out-of-the-box component.
Instead, I have opted for creating a custom **new Email** Action. It is now possible to populate the 'To' in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,  you cannot auto-populate 'To' field when sending an email through an opportunity.  Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjepUAB/to-field-to-auto-populate-when-sending-emails-through-an-opportunity).